# Add text pop up on link click

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

MY website is currently under construction so im trying to add a little pop up on the header links that says "coming soon" or something like that. You click it and it just pops up near the link.

This is the tutorial i was following but cant get it to work with my own code. So ill take anything at this point.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp

Id like something where all i have to do is add a certain class to each link and it just work once that class is added or something like that seems to me to be the best.

so idealy id like to add it to the about us, our work and services button.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <div class="new">
        <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="/aboutus/">ABOUT US</a></li>                   
        <li><a href="/ourwork/">OUR WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services/">SERVICES</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:bold');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:600');

@font-face {
  font-family: "roboto";
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url('images/bg.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
}

.logo {
  width: 150px;
  fill: white;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 23px 0px 0px 50px;
}

.logo svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

#hireus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 27px 50px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

.intro {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  /*
 top: 0;
 background-image: url('images/bg.png');
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
*/
}

.intro .inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
}


/* was ul */
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0
}

li {
  /*
 width: 120px;
 height: 40px;
*/
  margin: 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.new a {
  display: block;
  /*
 width: 120px;
 height: 40px;
*/
  /*  line-height: 40px; */
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  /*  margin: 20px 20px; */
  margin: 32px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.content {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 7%;
}

.content h1 {
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 520%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.content p {
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 420px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.btn {
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid 1px white;
  /*  padding: 10px 100px; */
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  width: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: #b0ccff;
  border: solid 1px #b0ccff;
}

.btn2 {
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid 1px #0B315C;
  /*  padding: 10px 100px; */
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #0B315C;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.btn2:hover {
  color: #b0ccff;
  border: solid 1px #b0ccff;
}

#scroll {
  color: green;
}

.title {
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.subtitle {
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #9D9D9D;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -45px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

#second {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
  width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
}

#Layer_1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#group2 {}

.whatwedo {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.subject {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 50px;
}

.subject img{
 width: 100px;
}

.subject h2 {
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.desc {
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #9D9D9D;
}

.group3 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 90px;
  
  
  
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  width: 550px;
}

form {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#forth {
  width: 100%;
}

#forth h2{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 14px;

}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0B315C;
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 42px;
  margin: -9px 0px 0px 240px;
}

.email-form {
    width: 400px;
}

.email-form input {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#hi{
 background-color: #F9F9F9;
 margin-top: -64px;
 padding-top: 150px;
 padding-bottom: 120px;
}






footer {
  background-color: #30659B;
  width: 100vw;
  
}

.logo2 {
  width: 150px;
  fill: white;
  display: block;
}

.nav2 {
  padding:0;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  display: flex;  /*Generates a flexbox layout with default flex direction as row */
  width: 100%; /* Not really required */
  height:100px;
  align-items: center; /*Aligns contents vertically */
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0px;
}

li {
  padding:0;
  font-family: proxima nova;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:center;
  margin:5px;
}
li:first-child{
margin-left:100px;
}
li:last-child{
margin-right:100px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}







/*--- Media Queries --*/

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .content {
    padding-bottom: 10%;
  }
  .content h1 {
    font-size: 400%
  }
  .btn {
    font-size: 110%;
    padding: 9px 43px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .content {
    padding-bottom: 12%;
  }
  .content h1 {
    font-size: 300%
  }
  .btn {
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 9px 43px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .content {
    padding-bottom: 14%;
  }
  .content h1 {
    font-size: 300%
  }
  .btn {
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 10px 44px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title>Launchpad | Web design and marketing</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="css/waypoints.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    
 <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/waypoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 
 
</head>
<body>
 

  
      <div class="logo">
        <svg class="logo" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 268 50"><title>Artboard 1</title><path         d="M46.26,10.5h6.46V35.17H65.55v5.69H46.26Z"/><path  d="M82.8,38.59a9.1,9.1,0,0,1-7,2.82c-3.5,0-7.65-2.37-7.65-7.28,0-5.14,4.14-7,7.65-7,2.91,0,5.51.91,7,2.69v-3c0-2.23-1.91-3.69-4.82-3.69a9.25,9.25,0,0,0-6.42,2.59l-2.18-3.87A14.42,14.42,0,0,1,79,18.33c5,0,9.6,2,9.6,8.33v14.2H82.8Zm0-5.74a5.78,5.78,0,0,0-4.64-1.91c-2.28,0-4.14,1.23-4.14,3.32s1.87,3.23,4.14,3.23a5.78,5.78,0,0,0,4.64-1.91Z"/><path d="M109.15,38.08a10.29,10.29,0,0,1-7.74,3.32c-4.82,0-7.1-2.64-7.1-6.92V18.88h5.78V32.21c0,3,1.59,4.05,4.05,4.05a6.47,6.47,0,0,0,5-2.5V18.88h5.78v22h-5.78Z"/><path d="M135.5,27.57c0-3-1.59-4.1-4.05-4.1a6.26,6.26,0,0,0-5,2.59V40.86h-5.78v-22h5.78v2.87a10.07,10.07,0,0,1,7.69-3.41c4.82,0,7.15,2.73,7.15,7V40.86H135.5Z"/><path d="M157.26,18.33c4.51,0,7.24,2,8.69,4l-3.78,3.5a5.44,5.44,0,0,0-4.64-2.37c-3.5,0-6,2.55-6,6.37s2.46,6.42,6,6.42a5.55,5.55,0,0,0,4.64-2.37L166,37.4c-1.46,2-4.19,4-8.69,4-6.78,0-11.65-4.78-11.65-11.56S150.48,18.33,157.26,18.33Z"/><path d="M184.61,27.48c0-3-1.59-4-4.1-4a6.4,6.4,0,0,0-5,2.59V40.86h-5.78V10.5h5.78V21.74a10.17,10.17,0,0,1,7.74-3.41c4.82,0,7.15,2.64,7.15,6.92V40.86h-5.78Z"/><path d="M196.12,49.24V18.88h5.78v2.78a8.49,8.49,0,0,1,6.78-3.32c5.64,0,9.74,4.19,9.74,11.52s-4.1,11.56-9.74,11.56A8.4,8.4,0,0,1,201.9,38v11.2Zm10.74-25.76a6.47,6.47,0,0,0-5,2.5v7.78a6.62,6.62,0,0,0,5,2.5c3.32,0,5.55-2.59,5.55-6.42S210.19,23.47,206.86,23.47Z"/><path d="M235.94,38.59a9.1,9.1,0,0,1-7,2.82c-3.51,0-7.65-2.37-7.65-7.28,0-5.14,4.14-7,7.65-7,2.91,0,5.51.91,7,2.69v-3c0-2.23-1.91-3.69-4.82-3.69a9.25,9.25,0,0,0-6.42,2.59l-2.18-3.87a14.42,14.42,0,0,1,9.6-3.46c5,0,9.6,2,9.6,8.33v14.2h-5.78Zm0-5.74a5.78,5.78,0,0,0-4.64-1.91c-2.28,0-4.14,1.23-4.14,3.32s1.87,3.23,4.14,3.23a5.78,5.78,0,0,0,4.64-1.91Z"/><path d="M262.57,38.08a8.62,8.62,0,0,1-6.78,3.32c-5.55,0-9.74-4.19-9.74-11.51s4.14-11.56,9.74-11.56a8.47,8.47,0,0,1,6.78,3.37V10.5h5.83V40.86h-5.83Zm0-12.11a6.36,6.36,0,0,0-5-2.5c-3.28,0-5.55,2.59-5.55,6.42s2.28,6.37,5.55,6.37a6.36,6.36,0,0,0,5-2.5Z"/><path d="M7.56,38.52l8.13,10.73a1.41,1.41,0,0,0,2.16,0L26,38.52a1.34,1.34,0,0,0-.56-2L18.53,33A4,4,0,0,0,15,33l-6.89,3.5A1.34,1.34,0,0,0,7.56,38.52Z"/><path d="M30.31,14.15,18.12.82a1.91,1.91,0,0,0-2.7,0L3.23,14.15a4,4,0,0,0-1,2.16L-.38,34.52c-.13.9,1,1.53,1.93,1.07L4.29,34.2l12.48-6.37L29.25,34.2,32,35.59c.92.47,2.06-.17,1.93-1.07l-2.57-18.2A4,4,0,0,0,30.31,14.15Z"/></svg>
    </div>
    
    <a id="hireus" href="/">HIRE US</a>

 <ul class="nav">
  <div class="new">
   <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="/aboutus/">ABOUT US</a></li>     
   <li><a href="/ourwork/">OUR WORK</a></li>
   <li><a href="/services/">SERVICES</a></li>
  </div>
 </ul>
 
 <section class="intro">
    
  <div class="inner"> 
   <div class="content">
    <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay="0.2s">
     <h1>Welcome to Launchpad</h1>
     <p>We are a creative agency who specializes in digital marketing and graphic design. Let us launch your business to the next level!</p>
    </section>
    
    <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay="0.7s">
     <a class="btn" href="#">Hire Us</a>
     <a class="btn2" href="#">Learn More</a>
    </section>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </section>
 
 <div id="second">
  <h2 class="title">What we do</h2>
  <p class="subtitle">Let us take your buisness to the next level.</p>
 </div>
 
 
 
 
 
 <div class="group2">
  <div class="whatwedo">
   
   <div class="subject" id="customdesign">
    <img src="images/customdesign.svg" alt="Custom Design">
    <h2 class="title2">Custom Design</h2>
    <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, scripta posidonium per ex. Duo ad unum graece luptatum, ius in dolores deleniti posidonium. </p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="subject" id="contentmarketing">
    <img src="images/contentmarketing.svg" alt="Content Mrketing">
    <h2 class="title2">Content Marketing</h2>
    <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, scripta posidonium per ex. Duo ad unum graece luptatum, ius in dolores deleniti posidonium. </p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="subject" id="emailmarketing">
    <img src="images/emailmarketing.svg" alt="Email Marketing">
    <h2 class="title2">Email Marketing</h2>
    <p class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, scripta posidonium per ex. Duo ad unum graece luptatum, ius in dolores deleniti posidonium. </p>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </div>
 
<div class="group3">
  <img src="images/testimonialbg.png" alt="Norway" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered">&ldquo;The team at Launchpad exceeded our expectations! 
They have a bright future ahead of them.&rdquo;<br>
<span style="font-weight: 600;">Sam Molloy, Unmatched Masonry</span></div>
</div>
 
<!--
  <div id="second">
  <h2 class="title">Our work</h2>
  <p class="subtitle">Nervous about taking off? Here's the portfolio.</p>
  </div>
-->
<div id="hi">
  <div id="forth">
   <h2 class="title">Lets get in touch</h2>
 
   <form action="mailto:contact@madebylaunchpad.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain" class="email-form">
    <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Your email address"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Lets talk">
   </form>

  </div>
  
</div>

<footer>
  <ul class="nav2">
    <li class="li2"><a href="/aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="/ourwork">OUR WORK</a></li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="/services">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li>
  <div class="logo2">
    <svg class="logo2" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 268 50"><title>Artboard 1</title><path         d="M46.26,10.5h6.46V35.17H65.55v5.69H46.26Z"/><path  d="M82.8,38.59a9.1,9.1,0,0,1-7,2.82c-3.5,0-7.65-2.37-7.65-7.28,0-5.14,4.14-7,7.65-7,2.91,0,5.51.91,7,2.69v-3c0-2.23-1.91-3.69-4.82-3.69a9.25,9.25,0,0,0-6.42,2.59l-2.18-3.87A14.42,14.42,0,0,1,79,18.33c5,0,9.6,2,9.6,8.33v14.2H82.8Zm0-5.74a5.78,5.78,0,0,0-4.64-1.91c-2.28,0-4.14,1.23-4.14,3.32s1.87,3.23,4.14,3.23a5.78,5.78,0,0,0,4.64-1.91Z"/><path d="M109.15,38.08a10.29,10.29,0,0,1-7.74,3.32c-4.82,0-7.1-2.64-7.1-6.92V18.88h5.78V32.21c0,3,1.59,4.05,4.05,4.05a6.47,6.47,0,0,0,5-2.5V18.88h5.78v22h-5.78Z"/><path d="M135.5,27.57c0-3-1.59-4.1-4.05-4.1a6.26,6.26,0,0,0-5,2.59V40.86h-5.78v-22h5.78v2.87a10.07,10.07,0,0,1,7.69-3.41c4.82,0,7.15,2.73,7.15,7V40.86H135.5Z"/><path d="M157.26,18.33c4.51,0,7.24,2,8.69,4l-3.78,3.5a5.44,5.44,0,0,0-4.64-2.37c-3.5,0-6,2.55-6,6.37s2.46,6.42,6,6.42a5.55,5.55,0,0,0,4.64-2.37L166,37.4c-1.46,2-4.19,4-8.69,4-6.78,0-11.65-4.78-11.65-11.56S150.48,18.33,157.26,18.33Z"/><path d="M184.61,27.48c0-3-1.59-4-4.1-4a6.4,6.4,0,0,0-5,2.59V40.86h-5.78V10.5h5.78V21.74a10.17,10.17,0,0,1,7.74-3.41c4.82,0,7.15,2.64,7.15,6.92V40.86h-5.78Z"/><path d="M196.12,49.24V18.88h5.78v2.78a8.49,8.49,0,0,1,6.78-3.32c5.64,0,9.74,4.19,9.74,11.52s-4.1,11.56-9.74,11.56A8.4,8.4,0,0,1,201.9,38v11.2Zm10.74-25.76a6.47,6.47,0,0,0-5,2.5v7.78a6.62,6.62,0,0,0,5,2.5c3.32,0,5.55-2.59,5.55-6.42S210.19,23.47,206.86,23.47Z"/><path d="M235.94,38.59a9.1,9.1,0,0,1-7,2.82c-3.51,0-7.65-2.37-7.65-7.28,0-5.14,4.14-7,7.65-7,2.91,0,5.51.91,7,2.69v-3c0-2.23-1.91-3.69-4.82-3.69a9.25,9.25,0,0,0-6.42,2.59l-2.18-3.87a14.42,14.42,0,0,1,9.6-3.46c5,0,9.6,2,9.6,8.33v14.2h-5.78Zm0-5.74a5.78,5.78,0,0,0-4.64-1.91c-2.28,0-4.14,1.23-4.14,3.32s1.87,3.23,4.14,3.23a5.78,5.78,0,0,0,4.64-1.91Z"/><path d="M262.57,38.08a8.62,8.62,0,0,1-6.78,3.32c-5.55,0-9.74-4.19-9.74-11.51s4.14-11.56,9.74-11.56a8.47,8.47,0,0,1,6.78,3.37V10.5h5.83V40.86h-5.83Zm0-12.11a6.36,6.36,0,0,0-5-2.5c-3.28,0-5.55,2.59-5.55,6.42s2.28,6.37,5.55,6.37a6.36,6.36,0,0,0,5-2.5Z"/><path d="M7.56,38.52l8.13,10.73a1.41,1.41,0,0,0,2.16,0L26,38.52a1.34,1.34,0,0,0-.56-2L18.53,33A4,4,0,0,0,15,33l-6.89,3.5A1.34,1.34,0,0,0,7.56,38.52Z"/><path d="M30.31,14.15,18.12.82a1.91,1.91,0,0,0-2.7,0L3.23,14.15a4,4,0,0,0-1,2.16L-.38,34.52c-.13.9,1,1.53,1.93,1.07L4.29,34.2l12.48-6.37L29.25,34.2,32,35.59c.92.47,2.06-.17,1.93-1.07l-2.57-18.2A4,4,0,0,0,30.31,14.15Z"/></svg>
  </div></li>
  <li class="li3"><a href="/aboutus">TWITTER</a></li>
  <li class="li3"><a href="/ourwork">FACEBOOK</a></li>
  <li class="li3"><a href="/services">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
 </ul>

</footer>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you just add `title="some message here"`, to each of the `a` elements, a tooltip will appear when the mouse hovers over the links.

Comment: And, please don't post links to your code at 3rd party sites, as those links can become broken over time and then your question becomes unintelligible to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code working:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center">
  <h2>Popup</h2>
  <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you just the copy the example from W3C?

Comment: The OP is trying to implement the same idea of tooltip in the code snippet they posted. Look at that.

Comment: He only needs to merge the code and have the `div` and `span` as the links.

Comment: So, include that in your answer instead of posting the same code he is referring to.

Comment: Why provide a link to a Fiddle, when you've got the code snippet right here?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Just in case he wanted to see it working in there where his code came from as he might not knew about the loading JavaScript part.

Comment: There's a big blue button in your answer that says "Run Code Snippet". That's all that's needed. Try to not post to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time.

Answer (score 0):

I built a pretty easy example for you and I'll run you through the code here.

First here it is in action:

```js
var selector = document.getElementById('showHide');

selector.onclick = function(){
 var show = document.getElementById('hidden');
  show.style.display = "block"
};
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <div class="new">
        <li  id="showHide"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
        <li id='hidden' style='display: none;'>Hello</li>
        <li><a href="/aboutus/">ABOUT US</a></li>                   
        <li><a href="/ourwork/">OUR WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services/">SERVICES</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

This is going to be your nav bar. As you can see i made some changes. I gave your home button an id so that we can call it later. I also added a new `<li>` tag that is hidden from site by "display: none".

```
<ul class="nav">
    <div class="new">
        <li id="showHide"><a href="/" >HOME</a></li>
        <li id='hidden' style='display: none;'>Hello</li>
        <li><a href="/aboutus/">ABOUT US</a></li>                   
        <li><a href="/ourwork/">OUR WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services/">SERVICES</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Here is the magic

```
var selector = document.getElementById('showHide');

selector.onclick = function(){
    var show = document.getElementById('hidden');
  show.style.display = "block"
};
```

At the top we create a selector variable to tell it what we want to target, which for us will be the Home button.

Below that we write a function that triggers when our selector is clicked. When it is triggered we define what we want to change(in this case that would be the element with the id of "hidden"). After that we simply edit it's display property to show.

Comment: okay not sure whats going on with the fiddle when i click on one of the links it pops up then it like reloads the fiddle inside of the preview area of the main fiddle. really weird. not happening to you?

Comment: As was already commented to the OP: *And, please don't post links to your code at 3rd party sites, as those links can become broken over time and then your question becomes unintelligible to future readers.*

Comment: or i suppose if i expand it it opens a error page. not what i want to happen

Comment: That is happening because of the default behaviour of the hyperlinks to redirect to another page just remove the href or change it to "#".

Comment: @WarrenBreedlove I just wanted to give him a place to see it in action and working. I put all the code from the fiddle on here to prevent degradation.

Comment: That is an improper use for `a` elements. `<a>` is for navigation, not a trigger for `click` events. If no navigation is occuring, no `a` should be used. Just set up a `click` event for the `li` instead.

Comment: @ScottMarcus If you did notice the problem the OP was facing, that was just a remedy to see how the output works. The user did code all of that, I'd say they would probably understand well enough what was it being referred to.

Comment: Okay it kinda worked. It popped up "hello" but it kinda messes up the nav. could a position absolute or relative fix this?

Comment: @ScottMarcus And I'm pretty sure that the OP needs the anchor tags, that's probably the reason for this query to get a tooltip to just notify the audience that it's being under construction instead of redirecting to a page and thus I'd say changing the href="#" for the time being isn't an issue.

Comment: @WarrenBreedlove you can position the element anywhere you like and in any way. You don't even need it to be right under the hello. Just make sure that the element you want to hide and then pop up has the id hidden.

Comment: @Highdef It is an issue because it is semantically the wrong tag to use and will cause problems for users that rely on assistive technologies, such as screen readers or for anyone relying on the back/forward buttons. The OP should not use `a` elements here. If it's temporary, then the tags should be added later, when they make sense to be there.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I was doing it as a quick fix. I understand your concern but I wanted to provide him a way to see the code and to be honest I didn't put much thought behind it. I'll make the fix so we don't lead anyone on.

Comment: It's important that we always try to provide good answers that address as many issues as we can. Leaving the code as is for an answer is OK, but you should at least put some text in the answer to indicate that there are issues with the code that require further consideration.

Comment: Well, if that's the issue then just change it to href="javascript: void(0);" The link will be just ignored as it identifies nothing.